# How to get constant feedback from a slider in Xcode with ApplescriptObjC?

Tags: xcode, slider, applescript-objc

I'm new to ApplescriptObjC as you'll probably see if you keep reading. I was wondering how to get constant feedback from a slider so that as soon as its value is 1 it runs script A and as soon as its value is changed to 0, it runs script B.

I know you can have actions for buttons like:

on buttonClicked_(sender)
do action
end buttonClicked_

But how can I have a one that constantly checks for a change in the slider's value and does the appropriate action? Is it similar to connecting a slider to a text box with the getStringValueFrom() thing?

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out how!

turns out on action_(sender) will work for sliders as well. They send the signal every time the item is clicked on and released whether a change exists or not. Then its a simple matter of an if statement to run two different series of actions depending on the value the slider was set to.